# Powershell bunched output with 2 Variables

Tags: powershell, quota

I am a noob with powershell so I need some help

I have 2 powershell request, they both work

```
$sum = 0
$quota = (Get-FsrmQuota -Path "$pfad" | Select-Object size)
$quota | Foreach { $sum +=$_.size}
$sum 

 Get-FsrmQuota -Path "$pfad" | Select-Object Description, Path, Size, PeakUsage, Usage |  Format-Table Path, 
@{Label="Size GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) }},
@{Label="PeakUsage GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.PeakUsage/1GB) }},
@{Label="Usage GB"; Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Usage/1GB) }} -AutoSize
```

Now I want all the informations I get in one Table (or some sort of bunched output )

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your select object as below.

```
Get-FsrmQuota -Path "$pfad" | Select-Object Description, Path, Size, PeakUsage, Usage, 
@{Label="Size GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Size/1GB) }},
@{Label="PeakUsage GB";  Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.PeakUsage/1GB) }},
@{Label="Usage GB"; Expression = { "{0:F0}" -f ($_.Usage/1GB) }} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```